# Does creation of new File(filename) object associate a process file descriptor with the object?

Tags: java, file, operating-system

Does the following statement:

new File(filename);

associate a process file descriptor with the File object? Tried to search the same but without any success.

Ideally, it should not statically associate the file descriptor with the File object. Whenever, function calls are executed a file descriptor should get associated with the File Object for the period of time when the function call gets executed.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no file descriptor, because `new File(filename)` does not **open** the file. It's just a easily manipulable representation of a path name.

File descriptors refer to open files. The fact that the file is not opened is not explicitly [documented](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html), but it follows from the principle of least surprise and from the fact that no exceptions are listed corresponding to failure to open the file.

Answer (score 2):

No, `new File(...)` only is an object representing the filename, without even checking that there exists a file (or directory) with this name and/or path.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can see this by examining the source of the File class yourself, from jdk 1.6.0_22:

```
public File(String pathname) {
    if (pathname == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    this.path = fs.normalize(pathname);
    this.prefixLength = fs.prefixLength(this.path);
}
```

Since you can call the File constructor with a path that doesn't yet exist, and since File objects can represent non-existent Files, it wouldn't be possible to associate descriptors with it.

Comment: Pedantic mode on: either `normalize` or `prefixLength` *could* have opened the file. While having the source code is a great asset, this kind of property should really be deduced from the API.

Comment: True, but by looking at the source code you could then look into these methods as well :) I didn't mean for this snippet to be the end of someone's query.